# Cross domain ajax json

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain, backbone.js

I'm on site.com trying to grab some json data from my node.js server serving on port 8080.

I get this Error message:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://site.com:8080/json/1. Origin http://site.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

my code:

```
    $.get('http://site.com:8080/1/', {}, function (Data) {
       console.log(Data);
    }, "json");
```

But it is the same domain though! :(

Also consider my backbone.js model:

```
model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: function() {
        return 'http://site.com:8080/' + this.id
    }
});
```

Is there any way to resolve this other than using jsonp?

Thanks.

Comment: The ports must match as well, otherwise jsonp is indeed the only option.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  IMHO, this should be clarified in the documentation (that ports are considered to be part of the domain).  Also, are requests across subdomains illegal as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you could modify your node.js server to allow Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).  This only works in modern browsers.  The simplest (and least secure) thing to do would be for your node.js server to emit the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://site.com".  You can learn more about CORS here: http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/

Comment: Hi could you explain why this wouldn't be secure?

Comment: The Origin request header indicates where the cross-domain request comes from.  The least secure thing to do would be to allow any third-party site to access your data (i.e. set "Access-Control-Allow-Orgin: *").  This may be what you want, if your data is public, but you should use it carefully.  A more secure thing is to read the Origin header and verify that it is an approved domain, and then only emit the "Access-Control-Allow-Orgin: http://site.com" header for approved domains.

Answer (score 7):

If you're making the call to the same domain, why do you have the absolute path in your `$.get` request?

Try this:

```
$.get('/1/', {}, function (Data) {
   console.log(Data);
}, "json");


model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: function() {
        return '/' + this.id
    }
});
```

If you are truly making the call on the same domain, then the above code should work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the call to the same domain **and port** your script was loaded from. You should be able to use jmort's code.